# I display numbers without leading or following zero (05 appears to me as 5 and 10 as 1). How to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, type-conversion, numbers

If I try to insert in a database, using combobox to choose a time or a date, numbers such as 05 or 10 (eg 05.10), these numbers are displayed without the zero. So I'm going to have 5 and 1 and I'm going to get this 5.1. Is there some way to display the 0 too or do you have to convert them to a string? If so, I have tried, but I get an error. I don't know if converting to string is the right solution. Do you have solutions?

I need to necessarily display them with 0 (for example 05 or 10). I don't need tkcalendar.

**UPDATE:** converting to string does not solve the problem. I'm not getting the error obviously, but the problem is the same. For example if I select 04 and 10 in the two comboboxes, I get 4.1. I would like to get 04.10

```
def date():
    day = combo_date_day.get()
    month = combo_date_month.get()
    result = (str)day + '.' + (str)month
    return result


combo_date_month = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Arial", 11), width=6, textvariable=month)
combo_date_month['values'] = ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12") 
combo_date_month.place(x=105, y=150)
combo_date_month.set("Month")


combo_data_day = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Arial", 11), width=6, textvariable=day)
combo_data_giorno['values'] = ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31") 
combo_data_day.place(x=15, y=150)
combo_data_day.set("Day")
```

Error

```
    result = (str)day + '.' + (str)month
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The error is here- the synatx for type casting is `typename(variable)`. So, you should write `str(day)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid type conversion. The syntax you have followed can be seen in Java.
But, in python,
the syntax is str(variable).

```
def date():
    day = combo_date_day.get()
    month = combo_date_month.get()
    result = str(day) + '.' + str(month)
    return result


#Example day or month
combo_date_month = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Arial", 11), width=6, textvariable=month)
combo_date_month['values'] = ("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12") 
combo_date_month.place(x=105, y=150)
combo_date_month.set("Month")
```

So, that is why , it is giving syntax error.

Comment: Converting to string did not resolve the error. I tried your code, thank you for the answer, but I still have the same problem. For example if I select 04 and 10 in the two comboboxes, I get 4.1. I would like to get 04.10

Comment: Kindly provide code about combo_date_day and get()

Comment: Done. Updated question. The code is the same for the months

Comment: Kindly tell how the combo_date_month and combo_date_day look like. give example pls.

Comment: For example if I select 04 and 10 in the two comboboxes day e month, I get 4.1. I would like to get 04.10